# random selection for slideshow start

Tags: jquery, loops, random, fadein

We have a slideshow that fades in/out 3 slides on a loop. Is there a way to randomly select one of the slides to start with?

Current code:

```
function startSlideshow(){
    $("#slide1").fadeIn(1000).delay(3500).fadeOut(1000); //5500
    $("#slide2").delay(5500).fadeIn(1000).delay(3500).fadeOut(1000); //11000
    $("#slide3").delay(11000).fadeIn(1000).delay(3500).fadeOut(1000, startSlideshow); //55000
}
```

This site and you all have been an incredible resource so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function startSlideshow(){
    var slides = ["#slide1","#slide2","#slide3"];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*slides.length);
    var slideSeq = slides.splice(rand).concat(slides);
    $(slideSeq[0]).fadeIn(1000).delay(3500).fadeOut(1000); //5500
    $(slideSeq[1]).delay(5500).fadeIn(1000).delay(3500).fadeOut(1000); //11000
    $(slideSeq[2]).delay(11000).fadeIn(1000).delay(3500).fadeOut(1000, startSlideshow); //55000
}
```

**NOTE:** I see that naab just posted something very similar to my solution while I was composing my answer, but I'm going to post anyway because my solutions preserves the slide sequence.

**EDIT:** I've put together a Fiddle to test my code. It fades three divs in sequence, starting with a randomly selected one.

http://jsfiddle.net/QmDt5/2/